# Chef - How to handle files installed only for testing?

Tags: testing, chef-infra

I have several files that will only be used during unit and integration testing and will never be used in production.  These files are tgz files that an upstream process will ultimately create but I need to have them available in order to run my tests.

I realize that the "files" directory is where files deployed by recipes are stored but what about testing files? Do files for unit testing go into "spec/files" and for integration testing go under "test/files"?

Or should these files also get stored in "files/unit_test", etc.? How is this normally handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a fixture cookbook under `test/` somewhere (mine live under `test/cookbook/`) and then set them up in your Berksfile.

```
group :test do
  cookbook 'foo_test', path: 'test/cookbook/'
end
```

Make sure you add it to the run list in the `.kitchen.yml` too.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying but these files aren't recipes or tests themselves.  Rather they are inputs to tests.

Comment: I'm saying make a second cookbook used only for your tests and then include the file in that cookbook.

Comment: @user3481957 Forgetting about chef for a second. When packaging code you want the release candidate to be identical in test as in production. If some artifacts should not be present in production, then you'll need to package them separately.

Comment: Hi Mark, I think you're misunderstanding.  The input data for the tests will be replaced by the actual input so there's no need for the input data files to exist in actual production.  But I need them to provide simulated test data while the project is under development.